# ListView of Expansion tiles is not scrollable

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want this screen to be scrollable so the ExpansionTile widgets can be scrolled whether they are collapsed or not.
Maybe I made a mistake that I can not find because I had something similar working on another project.
Thanks in advance!

code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      /*appBar: AppBar(actions: [IconButton(onPressed: (){Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => addNewCar_screen(),
      ));}, icon: Icon(Icons.add))],),*/
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade100,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                  height: 10,
                ),
                isLoading
                    ? Column(
                        children: [
                          ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => addNewCar_screen(),
                              ));
                            },
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                  Colors.grey.shade600),
                            ),
                            child: Icon(Icons.add),
                          ),

                          //SizedBox(width: 50,height:50,child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                        ],
                      )
                    : mycars.isEmpty
                        ? Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'keine Autos hier, erstelle eines',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30),
                              ),
                              ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => addNewCar_screen(),
                                  ));
                                },
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                          Colors.grey.shade600),
                                ),
                                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        : buildMyCars(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is the Widget building the expansion tiles:

```
  Widget buildMyCars() =>
        ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: mycars.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ExpansionTile(
                    leading: SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 40,
                      child: Image(
                        image: AssetImage('LOGOS/BMWLOGO.svg.png'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text('${mycars[index].marke}'+': '+'${mycars[index].modell}'+' ('+'${mycars[index].baujahr}'+')'),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    textColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                    collapsedIconColor: Colors.black87,
                    iconColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                    collapsedTextColor: Colors.black87,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        mycars[index].modell,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 25),
                      ),
                      Image(
                        image: AssetImage('Images/250px-BMW_M5_E39_(Blue).jpg'),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Daten:',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 2,
                        width: 300,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration:
                              BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 150,
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width: 150,
                                  //color: Colors.grey,
                                  child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Marke:',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                            )),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 1,
                                          width: 150,
                                          child: Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text('Modell:',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                            )),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 1,
                                          width: 150,
                                          child: Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text('Baujahr:',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                            )),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 1,
                                          width: 150,
                                          child: Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text('Motortype:',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                            )),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 1,
                                          width: 150,
                                          child: Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text('Hubraum:',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                            )),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 1,
                                          width: 150,
                                          child: Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text('KM:',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                            )),
                                      ]),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 150,
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  //color: Colors.blue,
                                  width: 150,
                                  child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(mycars[index].marke,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                            )),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 1,
                                          width: 150,
                                          child: Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(mycars[index].modell,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                            )),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 1,
                                          width: 150,
                                          child: Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(mycars[index].baujahr,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                            )),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 1,
                                          width: 150,
                                          child: Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(mycars[index].motor,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                            )),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 1,
                                          width: 150,
                                          child: Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(mycars[index].hubraum,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                            )),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 1,
                                          width: 150,
                                          child: Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                            mycars[index].kilometer.toString(), 
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                            )),
                                      ]),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  CarDetail_screen(CarId: mycars[index].id!),
                            ));

                            refreshMyCars();
                          },
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                Colors.grey.shade600),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            'Details',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
                          ))
                    ],
                  );
                }),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => addNewCar_screen(),
                ));
              },
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor:
                MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey.shade600),
              ),
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ],
        );

}
```

Result at the moment is:

- not scrollable
- no RenderFlex issues

Comment: Please remove all code that doesn't directly relate to your question

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your code inside Expanded widget
like:

```
Scaffold(
    body: Column(
        children: [
            Expanded(
                child: //your scrolling or non-scrolling Widgets
            ),
        ],
    ),
)
```

Comment: I tried this. It throws error: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
I guess this is because you should use Expanded only within a Column, Row or Flex??

Comment: Yes replace Container with Column widget

Answer (score 0):

I think because of the shrinkWrap property in your ListView builder, it made the content fit and it's not scrollable. Can you just put your buildMyCars(), as a child, inside a SingleChildScrollView widget ?

Comment: Tried both.. when I remove shrinkWrap I get Rendering issues.. 
And I put buildMyCars() in a SingleChildScrollView - unfortunately it did not change anything :-(

Comment: In another view of that app I tried:
ListView(
        children: (<Widget>[
      Container(),
     Container.. etc

and that worked.. I also tried to remove the logic, but that does not seem to be the problem. 
Do you think it could be the ListView.Builder?

Comment: What i was saying was that you should keep the shrinkWrap: true, but then you embed it in a SingleChildScrollView 
That should do the work

Comment: This is what I tried:

``

Comment: Widget buildMyCars() => Container(
    child:  ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: mycars.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(

              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
              
              child: ExpansionTile(

Comment: Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: 
(Then my logic)
          and then:
          : buildMyCars()

Comment: 1. I don't think you need to wrap your ListView.builder in a Container it's slightly useless
2. in your Widget build(BuildContext context), make sure you wrap : a scaffold -> SingleChildScrollView (shrink wrap false, primary true) -> buildMyCars()